# Artisan migrate:make --create command not making Schema::create()

Tags: laravel-4

I am following [Dayle Rees's tutorial on migrations in Laravel 4](http://daylerees.com/codebright/migrations). (And please see the link to understand my question). I am attempting to make some migration files using Artisan. I am at the paragraph beginning "We simply run...", followed by the example Artisan command:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users --create --table=users
```

...followed by the resultant code (snippet):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

But when I run the same artisan command, I don't get that. I get this instead:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        //
    });
}
```

Why?

Perhaps this is the result of a slightly later version of Laravel than Mr Rees was using for that tutorial, but the most annoying/puzzling thing is that the artisan command `--create` doesn't seem to work properly, ie. it is outputting

```
Schema::table()
```

instead of

```
Schema::create()
```

Comment: You're right.  This happens to me as well.  As you know, changing "table" to "create" resolves any issues this causes.

Comment: Thanks, James. Glad to hear I'm not overlooking something then. Slightly annoying, I hope they fix this.

Comment: FYI, James, I've got to the bottom of this- see my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, for anyone reading this, I've found the answer. I think perhaps this is a mistake in Dayle Rees's tutorial. Following the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#creating-migrations), the artisan command should be

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --create=users
```

---

So the moral of the story is that when the migration is for creating a table, the relevant command should be

```
php artisan migrate:make class_name --create=table_name
```

When modifying, the command is

```
php artisan migrate:make class_name --table=table_name
```

Comment: Its  php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
not migration:make

Comment: Yes, they changed it in Laravel 5. For Laravel 4 (which this question pertains to) the command is `migrate:make`.